# Does JDBC driver need to be upgraded when updating database version (IBM DB2 9.7)?

Tags: jdbc, db2, db2-luw

We will upgrade out IBM DB2 9.7 LUW to 10.5 LUW. Do we have to upgrade our JDBC driver too, or can we use existing one from 9.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should, in order to have everything at the same level. Each release has an upgrade in the JDBC drivers. You can check this page to see the different JDBC versions: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866

In addition, you can check the list of APARs  to check if you must change it because of an error. To see the list of enhancements in each version please visit the following link and look for the JDBC section of each fixpack: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21633303

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it depends. I'd check to see if the newer driver includes support for additional features that I want to make available to my application. If you don't need any of the new functionality the motivation to change the driver is reduced. If you have already been using the older driver with your app with no issues then you probably are not affected by any defects that are fixed in the newer driver. Keeping the same driver in place might reduce the QA you have to do as a result of upgrading the database. It would also mean you would not have to push a new driver out to all of your clients. You already know the driver you are currently using plays nicely with your app so by keeping it you can minimize the variables in the upgrade.

The protocols between the two databases are the same with the exception of new functionality added to 10.5. I can't really speak for what IBM supports in this regard but we (DataDirect) support multiple version of the database from one version of the driver. I suspect the same is true with the IBM driver. If you are curious to see how we handle it, we have a support matrix, that shows what versions of the database our current JDBC driver supports.